# how do I dereference a pointer which I got from a function in c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* CreateArray(int length){
    int arr[length];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < length; ++i){
        arr[i] = -25;
        int* ptr = &arr[i];
        printf("%p \n",ptr);
        printf("%d \n",*ptr);
    }
    printf("%d \n",arr[0]);
    int* location  = &arr;
    return location;
}




void main()
{
    int* arr = CreateArray(10);
    printf("pointer here is %p \n",arr);
    int num =  *arr;
    printf("%d",num);
}
```

when i run the program i want num  to be equal to arr[0] which was declared in the function but it doesn't do that for some reason

Comment: Your way to dereference the pointer is correct. But you return the address of a local variable with dynamic lifetime. This will not be valid any longer as soon as you return from that function. Assigning is to a separate variable first does not help.

Comment: You are returning address of a local variable which can lead to undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

The array `arr` is local to the function `CreateArray` and not marked as static, so it will deleted on returning from the function and cannot be used after that.

To avoid this, you should allocate arrays dynamically.

Also note that `&arr` is `int(*)[length]`, so it is not good to assign that to a variable of type `int*`.

```
int* CreateArray(int length){
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * length); /* allocate dynamically */
    if (arr == NULL) exit(1); /* check if allocation succeeded */
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < length; ++i){
        arr[i] = -25;
        int* ptr = &arr[i];
        printf("%p \n",(void*)ptr); /* void* should be passed for %p */
        printf("%d \n",*ptr);
    }
    printf("%d \n",arr[0]);
    int* location  = arr; /* assign arr, not &arr */
    return location;
}
```

Comment: To be clear: use dynamic allocation for arrays and other objects that you intend to return from your function, or that you want to continue to exist beyond the end of the function. You don't need to allocate *all* arrays dynamically.

Comment: thank you .at the end can i just use arr instead of location since the variable become redundant

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning a pointer created inside the function, and it will be deinitialized when the function is popped from the stack. This is called **dangling pointer**.

If you want to return a pointer, you have to create it on the heap:

```
int* arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * length);;
```

But pay attention, now you have to manage the garbage!